# how to calculate the time length of 0-1 sequence with hive?

Tags: sql, hive

Now I have a data like:

```
time(string) id(int)

201801051127 0

201801051130 0

201801051132 0

201801051135 1

201801051141 1

201801051145 0

201801051147 0
```

It has three different parts, and I want to calculate the time length of these three parts, such as the first zero sequence, the time length is 5 minutes. If I use 'group by 0 and 1', the first zero sequence would combine with the third zero sequence, which is not what I want. How I calculate the three parts' length with sql? My tried my-sql code is as follows:

```
SET @id_label:=0;
SELECT id_label,id,TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE,MIN(DATE1),MAX(DATE1)) FROM
(SELECT id, DATE1, id_label FROM (
SELECT id, str_to_date ( TIME,'%Y%m%d%H%i' ) DATE1,
@id_label := IF(@id = id, @id_label, @id_label+1)  id_label,
@id := id
FROM test.t
ORDER BY str_to_date ( TIME,'%Y%m%d%h%i' )
) a)b
GROUP BY id_label,id;
```

I don't know how to change it into hive code.

Comment: Oh that's right! The database is oracle!

Comment: Could you add the table definition (so we have names and data types) and the SQL you tried with (that has the `group by 0 and 1`)?

Comment: Please add what the datatypes are of the two columns. First one is a date or a number?

Comment: `SET @id_label:=0;` - this syntax sugesst that you are using [MySql database](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/mysql/info) but not [Oracle database](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/oracle/info), because this clause is incorrect in Oracle. Please edit your question and correct tags (remove `oracle` and add `mysql`).

Comment: yes, I confirm that I use hive. Before I realize the key, I am confused with those databases like mysql, oracle ,sqlserver with different sql format. The hive is another database based on hadoop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest some transformations:

- add an indication whether a row is the first one in its group (flag as 1, or null otherwise)
- count the number of such flags that precede a row to know its group number

Then you can just group by that new group number.

#### Oracle version (original question)

```
with q1 as (
    select to_date(time, 'YYYYMMDDHH24MI') time, id, 
           case id when lag(id) over(order by time) then null else 1 end first_in_group 
    from t
), q2 as (
    select time, id, count(first_in_group) over (order by time) grp_id
    from   q1
)
select   min(id) id, (max(time) - min(time)) * 24 * 60 minutes
from     q2
group by grp_id
order by grp_id
```

[SQL fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/541cf2/1)

#### Hive version

Different database engines use different functions to deal with date/time values, so use Hive's `unix_timestamp` and deal with the number of seconds it returns:

```
with q1 as (
    select unix_timestamp(time, 'yyyyMMddHHmm')/60 time, id, 
           case id when lag(id) over(order by time) then null else 1 end first_in_group 
    from t
), q2 as (
    select time, id, count(first_in_group) over (order by time) grp_id
    from   q1
)
select   min(id) id, max(time) - min(time) minutes
from     q2
group by grp_id
order by grp_id
```

Comment: I added a Hive version to my answer.

Comment: It is great! The idea is clear and easily understood! One problem existing is that I should select grp_id,min(id) id... so that the program can group by and order by it.

Answer (score 1):

Try This.

```
SELECT id, ( max( TO_DATE ( time,'YYYYMMDDHHMI' ) )
- min( TO_DATE ( time,'YYYYMMDDHHMI' ) ) ) *24*60 diff_in_minutes from 
(
select t.*,
row_number()   OVER ( ORDER BY 
                    TO_DATE ( time,'YYYYMMDDHHMI' ) )
- row_number() OVER ( PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY 
                    TO_DATE ( time,'YYYYMMDDHHMI' ) ) seq
FROM Table1 t ORDER BY time
  ) GROUP BY ID,seq
  ORDER BY max(time)
  ;
```

[**DEMO**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/cbe20/24)

**EDIT:** This answer was written considering that the OP had tagged `oracle`.Now it is changed to `hive`.

As an alternative in hive for `TO_DATE` in Oracle,

```
unix_timestamp(time, 'yyyyMMddhhmm')
```

could be used.

Comment: This query must have `ORDER BY time` after `.... FROM Table1 t`, that is: `FROM Table1 t ORDER BY time`. This is because (a quote from the Wikipeda): [ORDER BY is the only way to sort the rows in the result set. Without this clause, the relational database system may return the rows in any order.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_by). The database may return rows in any order, so ROWNUM may return unpredictable results.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The row_number is always powerful!