# Calculate the time length of 0-1 sequence with hive

Tags: sql, hive

The link ['calculate the time length'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48135388/how-to-calculate-the-time-length-of-0-1-sequence-with-hive/48135683?noredirect=1#comment83250121_48135683) has solved the problem which the time length is calculated in the sub-sequency.

The data is like:

```
time(string) id(int)

201801051127 0

201801051130 0

201801051132 0

201801051135 1

201801051141 1

201801051145 0

201801051147 0
```

Now I have some questions:

(1) the time length of the first sequence should begin with '201801051100', and end with the start time of next sequency like '201801051135', so the time length of the first sequence is 35;

(2) the time length of the second sequency should begin with the start time of it and end with the start time of next sequency;

(3) the time length of the final sequency should start with the start time of it and end with '201801051200'.

In order to satisfy these three calculation rules as the first sequence,the middle sequences and the final sequence, how to use hive to realize it base on the code written in ['calculate the time length'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48135388/how-to-calculate-the-time-length-of-0-1-sequence-with-hive/48135683?noredirect=1#comment83250121_48135683):

```
with q1 as (
select unix_timestamp(time, 'yyyyMMddHHmm')/60 time, id, 
       case id when lag(id) over(order by time) then null else 1 end 
first_in_group 
from t
), q2 as (
select time, id, count(first_in_group) over (order by time) grp_id
from   q1
)
select   min(id) id, max(time) - min(time) minutes
from     q2
group by grp_id
order by grp_id
```

Comment: Please use concrete examples.  Give input data and expected output data.  *(Without linking to another question, copy the data across if necessary.)*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve that with some minor modifications to the query:

```
with q1 as (
    select unix_timestamp(time, 'yyyyMMddHHmm')/60 time, id, 
           case id when lag(id) over(order by time) then null else 1 end 
                first_in_group 
    from t
), q2 as (
    select time, id
    from   q1
    where  first_in_group = 1
)
select   id, lead(time, 1, unix_timestamp('201801051200', 'yyyyMMddHHmm')/60) 
             over (order by time) - time 
             as minutes
from     q2
```